# alternating cases in a string - Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

I want to make every other char in a string uppercase.

So far I have this code...

```
    def task(s)

    n = s.length
    i = 1

    while i < n
      s[i] = s[i].upcase
      if s[i] == " "
        i = i 
      else
        i += 2
      end
    end
    s
  end
```

This works fine however, I want my function to ignore spaces.

This is my current output

```
expected: "hElLo ThErE fRiEnD"
got: "hElLo tHeRe fRiEnD"
```

How can I implement this?

Comment: What have you tried? I don't see anything in the code that checks to see if the character is a space or not--maybe start there?

Comment: The value of `n` is the length of the string; it will not change once its assigned. The space comparison would happen inside the `while` loop; the value of `n` is irrelevant.

Comment: If you've tried something, it's probably a good idea to show it. We might be able to explain what was wrong about your attempt, but not if we haven't seen the attempt.

Comment: If you set `i = i` (which is a no-op) the loop will never continue.

Comment: @TomLord thanks for the advice. I've changed my code to show what I was trying for future readers. Maybe you would be kind enough to explain what I was doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def upcase_every_so_many(str, freq)
  return str if freq.zero?
  str.gsub(/\p{L}/).with_index(1) { |c,i| (i % freq).zero? ? c.upcase : c }
end
```

```
str = "Now is the time for all good..."
```

```
puts "freq    upcase_every_so_many(freq)"
(0..17).each { |freq| puts "%03s   %020s" % [freq, upcase_every_so_many(str, freq)] }
```

```
freq    upcase_every_so_many(freq)
  0   Now is the time for all good...
  1   NOW IS THE TIME FOR ALL GOOD...
  2   NOw Is ThE tImE fOr AlL gOoD...
  3   NoW is The TimE foR alL goOd...
  4   Now Is thE timE for All gOod...
  5   Now iS the tIme foR all gOod...
  6   Now is The timE for alL good...
  7   Now is tHe time fOr all goOd...
  8   Now is thE time for All good...
  9   Now is the Time for alL good...
 10   Now is the tIme for all gOod...
 11   Now is the tiMe for all gooD...
 12   Now is the timE for all good...
 13   Now is the time For all good...
 14   Now is the time fOr all good...
 15   Now is the time foR all good...
 16   Now is the time for All good...
 17   Now is the time for aLl good...
```

`\p{L}` matches each Unicode letter.

Note that I have used the form of [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) that returns an enumerator and that I have chained that enumerator to [Enumerator#with_index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index).

---

Here's a variant of that method.

```
def upcase_every_so_many(str, freq)
  return str if freq.zero?
  enum = ([false]*(freq-1) + [true]).cycle
  str.gsub(/\p{L}/) { |c| enum.next ? c.upcase : c }
end
```

```
upcase_every_so_many(str, 4)
  #=> "Now Is thE timE for All gOod..."
```

See [Array#cycle](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-cycle).

For `freq = 4`,

```
arr = [false]*(freq-1) << true
  #=> [false, false, false, true]
enum = arr.cycle
  #=> #<Enumerator: [false, false, false, true]:cycle>
enum.next
  #=> false
enum.next
  #=> false
enum.next
  #=> false
enum.next
  #=> true
enum.next
  #=> false
... ad infinitum
```

Comment: To add a counter to each matched letter, you could also use `str.gsub(/\p{L}/).with_index { |c, i| ... }`

Comment: @Stefan, thank you for your suggestion, a good one that I've incorporated in an edit. It's curious that I didn't think of that considering that I often use the form of `gsub` that returns an enumerator.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying your approach, you could instead split the string into individual characters (`.split("")`), then use map (a method which returns a new array created by modifying each item in an array) to first check if a character is a space, then if it should be uppercased (the `up` variable), and flips the value of `up` before returning the character. This gives us an array of characters which we can then join together with `.join("")`.

```rb
def task(s)
  up = false

  s.split("").map do |char|
    if char != " "
      if up
        char = char.upcase
      end
      up = !up
    end
    char
  end.join("")
end

puts task("hello there friend")
```

Output:

```
hElLo ThErE fRiEnD
```

Comment: This is great! But then how could I modify this if I wanted to have every 3rd char in Upper case? The example output being 'heLlo TheRe fRieNd'

Comment: @TheMayerof If this was one of your requirements, it would have been better to make this clear in your original question. It is discouraging to have the goalposts shifted after putting in the effort of writing a solution.

Comment: You said *"I want to make every other char in a string uppercase."*, not *"I want to make every `n`th character uppercase"*.

Comment: @TomLord my apologies. My original question has been answered correctly. I am just curious about exploring the kata further.

Comment: For that, consider other ways to keep track of when to uppercase. Here we have a boolean value, which can be true/false, which means it will alternate every other character. If you instead used an integer and the modulo operator, you could alternate every n characters. For example, if `up` is a multiple of `n`, we uppercase the letter: `if up % n == 0 ...`

Answer (score 1):

Building on [this answer to your original question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67707886/1954610), here is an implementation that lets you pass in an `upcase_frequency` parameter - so you can capitalise every 2nd letter, or every 3rd letter, or every 100th letter, or whatever you want:

```
def task(s, upcase_frequency: 2)
  upcase_counter = 1

  s.split("").map do |char|
    if char != " "
      if upcase_counter % upcase_frequency == 0
        char = char.upcase
      end               
      upcase_counter += 1
    end                
    char               
  end.join("")         
end

puts task("hello there friend")
  # => hElLo ThErE fRiEnD

puts task("hello there friend", upcase_frequency: 3)
  # => heLlo TheRe fRieNd
```

Comment: There are countless other ways you could extend it further, like: Special handling for punctuation? Or for numbers? Or for other whitespace, like newlines? Or for characters that are already upper-case?........

Comment: A small thing: substituting `s.each_char` (which returns an enumerator) for `s.split("")` avoids the creation of the array `s.split("")`. It arguably reads better as well. (Tom knows this.)